# Grab variable within a function

Tags: jquery

Im new on jQuery and im learning by building my first project for a DYI Web Interface.

This is part of the code im using:

```
var lights_array = [];
$.getJSON("resources/php/getjson.php",function(json){
    var verajson = json; 
    var lights_obj = verajson.devices;

    for (i = 0; i < verajson.devices.length; i++) { 
        var lights_ids = verajson.devices[i].id;
        lights_array.push(lights_ids);  
    } 
    console.log(lights_array[9]); //I get on console the value of the index 9 on the console
});

console.log(lights_array[9]);   //I get an "underfined" here
```

I want to be able to call the lights_array as a global array to use its values when needed.

any assistance will be greatly appreciated

thanks

J

Comment: because `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers and comments point out, `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous. The function returns immediately, *before* the server responds with the JSON data. The reference to `lights_array` at the bottom of the code runs before you have received and processed the data inside the callback.

So the first thing you should do is move the declaration of `lights_array` *inside* the callback instead of before the `$.getJSON()` call. This way you won't be able to make the mistake of trying to access it outside the callback. If you want to use this data elsewhere in your code, you can write a function and call that function from the callback, passing the array as an argument.

cs1193's answer says that you need to use promises (the `$.when()` and `then()` methods). This is incorrect. Promises are simply a nice way to organize your callback functions. You should definitely learn about them and may want to use them in your code, but you don't *have* to use them. An ordinary callback works equally well. The issue you're facing here is trying to use the data outside the asynchronous callback, not whether the callback is reached via a promise or directly passed into the `$.getJSON()` call. And if you do use a promise, `then()` is the wrong method to use; the one you want here is `done()`.

There are also a couple of redundant unused variables in the code. This is probably just left over from testing you were doing, but it's something you'll want to clean up.

And I would suggest using `$.map()` to generate your `lights_array` instead of the `for` loop. It's simpler and easier to read.

Since you're new to JavaScript, I'll also make a few suggestions on naming conventions.

First a minor point, but `names_with_underscores` are not really idiomatic in JavaScript. The more common convention is `camelCaseNames` for variables, methods, and ordinary functions, and `PascalCaseNames` (first letter capitalized) for constructor functions.

Also watch out for singular vs. plural names. You have the (unused) singular name `lights_obj` which is an *array* of devices (it's the same as `verajson.devices`). And the plural name `lights_ids` refers to a *single* device object. It's not plural, and it's not an `id` either, it's a object containing an `id`.

Putting all this together, the code might look like this:

```
$.getJSON( "resources/php/getjson.php", function( data ) {
    var lights = $.map( data.devices, function( device ) {
        return device.id;
    });
    console.log( lights[9] );
    someFunction( lights );  // to use the lights array elsewhere
});
```

If you'd like to try using a promise, note that `$.getJSON` *returns* a promise. There's no need to wrap it inside a `$.when()` call. You could do this:

```
$.getJSON( "resources/php/getjson.php" )
    .done( function( data ) {
        var lights = $.map( data.devices, function( device ) {
            return device.id;
        });
        console.log( lights[9] );
        someFunction( lights );  // to use the lights array elsewhere
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Ill try and let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

The getJson is an asynchronous method, therefore when you reach the external part of code the array may have not been populated yet. If you want to do some operations on the array, you should put your logic in the done callback of the getJson method.

Comment: Thanks Lino.  Any chance you could show me how to?  Im fairly new and im better with examples, anyways, in case you have  the chance

Answer (score 0):

See the problem with the code is it works asynchronously, wherein `lights_array[9]` would execute first then the `getPost` method, so it would remain largely undefined as it would not know what is in `9` index eventhough the array is declared. You got to use promises, `$.when` and `then` inorder to assign and access data.

```
var lights_array = [];
$.when($.getJSON("resources/php/getjson.php",function(data){ 
})).then(function(json){
    var verajson = json; 
    var lights_obj = verajson.devices;

    for (i = 0; i < verajson.devices.length; i++) { 
        var lights_ids = verajson.devices[i].id;
        lights_array.push(lights_ids);  
    } 
    console.log(lights_array[9]); //I get on console the value of the index 9 on the console
});
console.log(lights_array[9]);   //I get an "underfined" here
```

Hope this should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  I used your code but still get the undefined.